# java 8 not configured in ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, java-8, ubuntu-14.04

When I try to install something there is always this java dependency problem, I have working java version 1.8 but I don't know what i have done wrong.

On giving this command in ubuntu

```
 sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

It results

```
Setting up oracle-java8-installer (8u121-1~webupd8~0) ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing package oracle-java8-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of oracle-java8-set-default:
 oracle-java8-set-default depends on oracle-java8-installer; however:
  Package oracle-java8-installer is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package oracle-java8-set-default (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java8-installer
 oracle-java8-set-default
```

---

How I can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Better install Open JDK:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
```

---

If you don't use testing repository, you can take:

> Unable to locate package openjdk-8-jdk

In this case you must include testing repository or do this:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

---

[Open JDK](http://openjdk.java.net/) — it's JDK with open sources code. It better installs in Linux (and installs automatically). And Open JDK work absolute like Oracle JDK.

---

Try to clear `sources.list` (but make backup, I could be wrong) and paste in this file it:

```
deb http://01.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main 
deb-src http://01.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main
```

Then make:

`sudo apt-get autoclean`

`sudo apt-get -f install`

`sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk`

Comment: It says  "Unable to locate package openjdk-8-jdk"

Comment: @secretcoder, hm... Wait. I try to do it in my Ubuntu.

Comment: sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdkSome packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 openjdk-7-jdk : Depends: openjdk-7-jre (= 7u51-2.4.6-1ubuntu4)
                 Recommends: libxt-dev but it is not going to be installed

Comment: @secretcoder, please show your file `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

Comment: deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted multiverse
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted multiverse
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ trusty partner

Comment: @secretcoder, what is version of Your Ubuntu and, accidentally, have ARM processor?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
no its intel

Comment: on giving sudo apt-get -f install,

Comment: download failed
Oracle JDK 8 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing package oracle-java8-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of oracle-java8-set-default:
 oracle-java8-set-default depends on oracle-java8-installer; however:
  Package oracle-java8-installer is not configured yet.

Comment: dpkg: error processing package oracle-java8-set-default (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: @secretcoder, do this commands and retry from `autoclean`: `dpkg -p oracle-java8-installer` and `dpkg -p oracle-java8-set-default`.

Comment: autoclean: dpkg -p oracle-java8-installer,  is this a command?

Comment: @secretcoder, no... When you will maked commands with `dpkg`, you must try retry streps, which I wrote in answer, starts from command with aoutoclean.

Comment: same error,one thing i forgot to tell you that during install command there is always some read errors flashing an then download failed proceeding with above errors

Comment: @secretcoder, hm... Sorry, but I don't know how to fix this. When I take similar errors in my Debian, I somehow fix it. But, in result, appeared new errors, and I reinstall OS.... Maybe you must install the newest Ubuntu. Your OS is old and has problems. I install Ubuntu 16 one month ago in Virtual Box and OpenJdk installed without problems. And, I wonder: you, accidentally, not from Russia?)

Comment: No,I from India. Thank you so much for helping me